# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join'). react-native metro server

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

When I run a react-native application and metro start automatically with this error but if I start metro server manually with `npx react-native start` it works.

[image]

Comment: mertro bundler will work when you run it manually as it is just keeping a watch on the code changes and there are no changes at the beginning, but what you mean by automatic bundler start is you are using a command like `npx react-native run-android` which actually builds the app for android and the build is actually breaking.

Even you can see on the top, it shows metro is running on port 8081, so it is actually the build which is breaking

Comment: please share some code snippets too which you think are causing the issue (as the error shows cannot read properties of undefined, reading join), check the code where you are using join

Comment: I have checked join, it's in Gemfile `ruby File.read(File.join(__dir__, '.ruby-version')).strip`

Comment: so you are trying to run on ios, please check the setup process for ios, maybe you are missing something

Comment: managed to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with react-native 0.63.3, but I think this advice might help for other versions as well. The crux of the matter is that you have some package that overrides metro-config with an older version. In my case, it was the package react-native-carousel-swiper@^1.0.11, and it was pulling in metro-config@0.56.4 while react-native should be pulling in a newer version.

You can simply check this with the following commands at the root of your react-native project:

```
yarn why metro-config
```

And you'll get a response somewhat like this:

```
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "metro-config"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "metro-config@0.56.4"
info Has been hoisted to "metro-config"
info Reasons this module exists
   - Hoisted from "metro#metro-config"
   - Hoisted from "react-native-carousel-swiper#react-native#@react-native-community#cli#metro-config"
info Disk size without dependencies: "1.32MB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "13.03MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "1.32MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 252
=> Found "@react-native-community/cli#metro-config@0.59.0"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "react-native#@react-native-community#cli" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "react-native#@react-native-community#cli#metro#metro-config"
info Disk size without dependencies: "100KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "11.29MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "100KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 252
✨  Done in 1.82s.
```

This way, you'll understand which package is pulling in an older version of metro-config. Consequently, you can resolve the issue by updating the outdated package.